# Spree API and New Relic monitoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, newrelic

I've got problem with monitoring my app with New Relic.

I have latest Spree engine mounted in my routes and own controller to serve as root.

For some reason, New Relic gathers only data from this root route, any call to Spree JSON API is ignored and don't show up in Dashboard, so I can see only one transaction and it's pretty useless.

Is there any way to enable monitoring on whole mounted app? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you're running on Rails 4.0 or later, adding the following to `app/controllers/spree/api/base_controller_decorator.rb` or some equivalent location should get instrumentation wired up:

```
class Spree::Api::BaseController
  include ActionController::Instrumentation
end
```

This works because on Rails 4.0 and later New Relic's controller instrumentation is based off `ActiveSupport::Notifications`, and `include ActionController::Instrumentation` gets those events flowing.

Comment: Documentation for this has been updated at http://docs.newrelic.com/docs/ruby/adding-instrumentation-to-actioncontroller-metal.

Comment: FYI, as of Spree 2.2 the Api inherits from ActionController::Base instead of ActionController::Metal so this should no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is happening because Spree's API is inheriting from `ActionController::Metal`, where NewRelic doesn't hook into.

Check here: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/6ac62c32f91e6626b338564aab7a7ad570cbd4c3/api/app/controllers/spree/api/base_controller.rb#L5

This is probably a good argument for switching away from this within Spree, so please submit an issue for that.

Comment: So, your suggest is to try make BaseController inherit from ActionController::Base?

Comment: At some point, yes. If that's what it's going to take to get some New Relic info on our API to find out the painpoints in larger Spree apps, then we should probably go down that path. Again: please submit an issue about this because I am likely to forget.

Comment: Found a way to hook Newrelic into Metal controller, but I will create issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to bypass the problem in [this article](http://laika.io/2013/10/03/newrelic-ac-metal.html).

Create app/controllers/spree/api/base_controller_decorator.rb with following code:

```
require 'new_relic/agent/instrumentation/action_controller_subscriber'
require 'new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails4/action_controller'

Spree::Api::BaseController.class_eval do
  before_filter :check_for_user

  include NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::ControllerInstrumentation
  include NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::Rails4::ActionController

  NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::ActionControllerSubscriber \
    .subscribe(/^process_action.action_controller$/)

end
```